# EncodeToJPG is too slow. Blocking main thread.Is there new way alternative？

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
 private byte[] EncodingJPG(Texture2D texture2D)
 {
     byte[] bytes = texture2D.EncodeToJPG(20);
     return bytes;
 }
```

EncodeToJPG is too slow. Blocking main thread.I have already tried Coroutine,but still very slow.If I need to execute this method continuously,What should I do？

Comment: Don't run it on the main thread if you don't want it to block

Comment: @JoePhillips You can't call `EncodeToJPG` outside the main Thread. It will throw an exception

Comment: You can try this multithreaded encoder, I have not tested it myself: https://github.com/vinaysshenoy/unity-jpeg-encoder